# Sane defaults for MongoDB on OSX?

Tags: macos, mongodb, configuration

I installed MongoDB and have set it up like so:

DB path: `/data/db`

System-wide config file: `/usr/local/mongodb/mongod.conf`

launchctl plist: `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.mongodb.mongod.plist`

Log: `/var/log/mongodb/output.log`

Binary: `/usr/local/bin/mongod`

**Are there any defaults on all these paths?**

I am looking for defaults that are in line with MongoDB **and** with OS X. References for the answers would be lovely. :-)

Comment: you got the definitive answer - why the bounty?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky, the answer is an opinion and it is a pretty good one but I would like to receive some more opinions on the matter as well.

Comment: it's not an opinion. it's rather factual.

Comment: An answer containing "For my own installation, I use the following" looks like a personal opinion to me. :-)

Answer (score 17):

The only one of these values for which MongoDB has a default is the data path, which is `/data/db`. MongoDB by itself does not ship with a config file, nor does it log to a file by default, and the choice of where to install the binaries is entirely up to you.

For my own installation, I use the following:

- config: `/usr/local/mongo/mongod.conf`
- dbpath: `/usr/local/mongo/data`
- logging: `/private/var/etc/mongodb.log` (this then shows up automatically in the Console app)
- launchctl: `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.mongodb.mongod.plist`

The only other note I'd make is that it is probably worth raising the hard and soft limits for NumberOfFiles, as MongoDB uses this limit to determine the maximum number of connections that it will accept. On some versions, OS X defaults this number to 256, which means you can have a maximum of around 205 connections, which may be too low even for a development environment. I have the following in my launchctl plist:

```xml
<key>HardResourceLimits</key>
<dict>
  <key>NumberOfFiles</key>
  <integer>1024</integer>
</dict>
<key>SoftResourceLimits</key>
<dict>
  <key>NumberOfFiles</key>
  <integer>1024</integer>
</dict>
```

Comment: I've added this to the homebrew plist so hopefully nobody will ever have to manually set this again: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/17523

Answer (score 13):

On Mac I'd recommend you install mongo with [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) which installs all programs into `/usr/local`. You will have the default paths:

- config: `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`
- data dir: `/usr/local/var/mongodb`
- log: `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`
- plist file: `/usr/local/opt/mongodb/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist`

To install: `brew install mongodb`

to restart mongo you do:

```
launchctl stop homebrew.mxcl.mongodb
launchctl start homebrew.mxcl.mongodb
```

Comment: @dcrosta's answer puts the log in `/private/var/etc/mongodb.log` in order to make it visible in Console.app which I find pretty useful. Will installing mongo via homebrew make the log visible there as well?

Comment: No, it does not. Of course you can add it manually there or create a symlink. I prefer to use tail or less on the command line.

Comment: the default `data` directory is no longer `/usr/local/var/mongod/` but instead `/data/db/`, any idea how to change the default back to `/usr/local/var/mongodb/`? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed mongodb, like I did but have an older version simply run

```
brew upgrade mongodb
```

This should update your mongodb to the latest available package.